# GDB similar address output

Tags: assembly, gdb

Can someone explain why all four print statements below print out the same instruction pointer even though dereferencing is going on for two of them. Moreover why is $rip void (*)()? I'm just struggling to see the subtle differences.

```
(gdb) print *$rip
$6 = {void ()} 0x55555555460e <main+20>
(gdb) print $rip
$7 = (void (*)()) 0x55555555460e <main+20>
(gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x55555555460e <main+20>:    callq  0x55555555461a <foo>
(gdb) x/i *$rip
=> 0x55555555460e <main+20>:    callq  0x55555555461a <foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

GDB uses the symbols in the elf file to know the `type` of what you are trying to print. For example, if you try to print an array of characters, it would print it as a string .. etc.

Now, this address, is inside `main()` by an offset that is 20 bytes from the beginning of `main()`. It's code. A generic function pointer type `void (*)()` is assumed. I think as in C, `&main` is the same as `main`, both are pointers to functions, this is why `print *$rip` prints the same as `print $rip` but with a difference in the type. But nothing to print other than the contents of the instruction at this location.

`x/i` on the other hand, prints the disassemble of the contents of that address.

If you want to print the contents, for example, as array of ints, you'd need to cast the pointer and use something like:

```
print *(unsigned *) $rip
```

Comment: Yes, when used in an expression, `main`, `&main`, and `*main` technically all have the same type in C, which is pointer to function. See this https://godbolt.org/z/jjdoPG1x5
 here, we're looking at the output window (not the generated code) to see the warnings GCC prints regarding type mismatches. Since `main` is a constant rather than a variable, as a symbol, we can also describe it more simply as a function. GDB is doing something like this, extra but attempting to be sensible in interpreting those items